# Solving the equation $ax + c \equiv b \mod {n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Alright, I can go through and solve equations that do not have the "$+ c$" involved, i.e.: $ax \equiv b \mod{n}$.  However, I do not know what to do when a "$+ c$" is incorporated.  How does that $c$ affect the final answer / the process?

My best guess would be when pulling back to integers, without "$+ c$" you would get: $ax + ny = b$.

So do I simply need to subtract the c and move it to the right hand side?
$ax + ny = b - c$.

Thanks in advance!

Sean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just subtract it to begin with: $$ax\equiv d\pmod n$$ where $d=b-c$, reducing it to a problem already solved.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just as for integer equations, one may subtract an integer from both sides of a congruence, i.e.

$\begin{array}{rrl}
 &\rm a+b &\equiv&\rm c\qquad\quad\  \rm(mod\ n) \\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\iff &\rm\ \ a+b &=&\rm c\quad\ \ \ +\ \ \ \quad k\ n &\rm for\quad k\in\mathbb Z \\
\iff &\rm\ \  a &=&\rm c\!-\!b\ \ \ +\ \ \ k\ n &\rm for\quad k\in\mathbb Z \\
\iff &\rm\ \ a &\equiv&\rm c\!-\!b\:\ \ \ \rm (mod\ n)
\end{array}$